# Django query OneToMany by multiple fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have schema similar to this one (obviously this one is simplified)

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = TextField()
    date_vaccinated = DateTimeField(null=True)  # null indicates no vaccination
    owner = ForeignKey(Person, related_key="pet")

class Person(models.Model):
    name = TextField()


people_with_a_vaccinated_pet_named_rex = 
Person.objects.filter(pet__date_vaccinated__isnull=False, pet__name="Rex")
```

As indicated in the last line I'm trying to find all people who have a pet called Rex that is also vaccinated.
The query I wrote will find all people with a pet named rex, and a vaccinated pet (not necessarily the same pet..)

Is there a way to query with multiple conditions on the same OneToMany relation?

P.S the real query I'm trying to write is more similar to the following:

```
Person.objecs.filter(pet__class1__date__isnull=False, pet__class1__class2__class3__name="blabla")
```

where I want to reach class 3 only through class1 instances that their date is not null

Comment: That is already happinging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *already* the case. In this filter, you make queries on the *same* one-to-many relation.

Indeed, your query:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    pet__date_vaccinated__isnull=False,
    pet__name='Rex'
)
```

Is translated to a database query that looks like:

```
SELECT person.*
FROM person
INNER JOIN pet ON pet.owner = person.id
WHERE pet.date_vaccinated IS NOT NULL AND pet.name = 'Rex'
```

We thus make *one* JOIN on the `Pet` model, and we thus filter on the *same* `Pet`.

This is the same for your second case, again it will join once on the `pet`, `class1`, `class2`, and `class3`, and thus the filter conditions are performed on the same related object.

If you want to query on (possibly) different object, you can filter with:

```
# get persons that have a Pet that has a name 'Rex',
# and a (possibly) different Pet that is vaccinated

Person.objects.filter(
    pet__date_vaccinated__isnull=False
).filter(
    pet__name='Rex'
)
```